# Reading from a SQLite DB is failing in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, system.data.sqlite

So I'm pretty new to .NET but I've been coding for years.  I'm trying to accomplish a relatively simple task:  Read a table in a SQLite database, and populate a few textboxes

I've read everything on here that's related, and even used the code examples.  For whatever reason, my code will not function as expected.

In fact, in the code I"m posting below, after the conn.Open statement, nothing else even executes, it simply goes straight to opening the form.  I know this because I've set breakpoints, and I"m trying to step through the code, but it never reaches cmd = conn.CreateCommand.

That said, any insight would amazing!  Here's every stitch of code in the project:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SQLite

Public Class frmAdmin

Public conn As SQLiteConnection
Public dr As SQLiteDataReader

Private Sub frmAdmin_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim connString As String = "C:\Users\collensm\Documents\Development\BioDataProject\BioData\biodata.db"
    conn = New SQLiteConnection(connString)
    conn.Open()

    Dim cmd As SQLiteCommand

    cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [_AppConfig].* FROM [_AppConfig];"

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    While dr.Read
        Select Case dr("KeyName")
            Case = "DBPath" : txtDBPath.Text = dr("KeyValue")
            Case = "OraService" : txtOraService.Text = dr("KeyValue")
            Case = "OraSID" : txtOraSID.Text = dr("KeyValue")
            Case = "OraPort" : txtOraPort.Text = dr("KeyValue")
            Case = "OraHost" : txtOraHost.Text = dr("KeyValue")
            Case = "FTPAddress" : txtFTPAddress.Text = dr("KeyValue")
            Case = "FTPUser" : txtFTPUser.Text = dr("KeyValue")
                'Case = "FTPPassword"
        End Select

    End While
End Sub
```

PS: I've also installed the SQLite NuGet Package using the solutions 'Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..." option.

Thanks in advance!

Michael

Comment: An exception thrown in the form's load event will cause the event handler to exit. From your description, it sounds as though you are getting an exception on the `conn.Open()` statement.

Comment: I don't think that connection string can be right. At the least, it should be "Data Source = C:\Users blah blah blah"

Comment: If you have really read much here on DB Ops you'd have read that a single global connection and datareader are a bad idea.  The problem though is almost certainly an exception.  Move the code to a button click or Form Shown to debug it.  Also www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: Mary is correct - that's not a typical connstring - here are examples - most of which you'll need to supply name/value pairs depending on the DB: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/